# format command output with variable and fixed space

Tags: text-processing, echo, printf, text-formatting

How can I achieve this best maintaining the hierarchy on the left and aligning the size value on the right?
Also, at the same time I'd like to round the size to one or two digits.
I tried with `printf` but couldn't figure it out how to keep this format.

```
$ port rdeps mtr 2>/dev/null | sed -E "1 s/.*of (.*) @.*/\1/" | while IFS= read -r line; do echo -e "$line" \\t\\t\\t\\t $(port space --units MiB --total $line 2>/dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2); done
mtr                  0.088 MiB
  pkgconfig                  0.615 MiB
    libiconv                 6.270 MiB
      gperf                  0.0 MiB
  glib2                  46.092 MiB
    xz               1.679 MiB
      gettext                24.825 MiB
        expat                1.109 MiB
        ncurses                  15.171 MiB
    libxml2                  10.405 MiB
      zlib               0.721 MiB
    libffi               0.141 MiB
    pcre                 5.954 MiB
      bzip2                  0.647 MiB
      libedit                0.795 MiB
```

This should look like this

```
mtr                          0.08 MiB
  pkgconfig                  0.61 MiB
    libiconv                 6.27 MiB
      gperf                  0.00 MiB
  glib2                     46.09 MiB
    xz                       1.67 MiB
      gettext               24.82 MiB
        expat                1.10 MiB
        ncurses             15.17 MiB
    libxml2                 10.40 MiB
      zlib                   0.72 MiB
    libffi                   0.14 MiB
    pcre                     5.95 MiB
      bzip2                  0.64 MiB
      libedit                0.79 MiB
```

Comment: Thanks for describing what you want to do (or at least making an attempt to do so) and showing us what you tried.  Now, please, show us what the input looks like, and what you want the output to look like.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-Man, the output you can see there already and the input (to the `while` loop, if you refer to this) is what you see on your left — each line is echoed plus four tabs and the output of a command that's run on this same line. On the left you have a hierarchy of dependencies, that I want to preserve — on the right you have the size value for each one separated by four tabs. Instead of four tabs, I'd like to have those numbers aligned by its floating point, say at column 40 or so. You can see this in `pkgconfig` and the 2 following lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches:

## With Rounding

As you appear to realize, `printf` is a great tool for formatted printing. 
`%f` is the format to output a “floating point number”,
i.e., a number that is not an integer,
i.e., a number that includes a fractional part. 
As with all printf formats,
a number (an integer!) immediately after the `%`
specifies the overall length of the formatted output,
possibly including spaces. 
This number can be followed by a period (**`.`**) and another number,
which specifies the number of decimal positions
(digits to the right of the decimal point) to display. 
So, for example, the commands

```
printf "%12.2f\n" 1000000
printf "%12.2f\n" 1000
printf "%12.2f\n" 1
printf "%12.2f\n" 1.2345
printf "%12.2f\n" 1.6789
          ︙
```

will produce the output

```
  1000000.00
     1000.00
        1.00
        1.23
        1.68
         ︙
```

Note that `1.6789` got *rounded up* to `1.68`.

So you should be able to get the result you want with this command:

```
port rdeps mtr 2>/dev/null | sed -E "1 s/.*of (.*) @.*/\1/" |
     while IFS= read -r line
     do
         space="$(port space --units MiB --total $line 2>/dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2)"
         space_num=${space% *}
         space_mib=${space#* }
         printf "%-20s%12.2f %s\n" "$line" "$space_num" "$space_mib"
     done
```

The `space=$(…)` command is just the `port space` command substitution
that we’ve been using all along, but with the result
(which looks like `0.088 MiB`, for example)
assigned to a temporary variable, `space`. 
Then `space_num=${space% *}` sets `space_num` to the part of that
before the space character (i.e., the number; `0.088` in this example),
and `space_mib=${space#* }` sets `space_mib` to the part
after the space character (i.e., the units, `MiB`). 
Finally we glue all the parts together,
using `printf` `%12.2f` to display the number to two decimal places,
rounding to the nearest hundredth,
and lining up on the decimal points (as in the earlier example). 
For your data, this looks like

```
mtr                         0.09 MiB
  pkgconfig                 0.62 MiB
    libiconv                6.27 MiB
      gperf                 0.00 MiB
  glib2                    46.09 MiB
    xz                      1.68 MiB
      gettext              24.83 MiB
        expat               1.11 MiB
        ncurses            15.17 MiB
    libxml2                10.40 MiB
      zlib                  0.72 MiB
    libffi                  0.14 MiB
    pcre                    5.95 MiB
      bzip2                 0.65 MiB
      libedit               0.80 MiB
```

Note that `0.088 MiB` got rounded up to `0.09 MiB`

Note also that `space_mib` is always set to `MiB`,
so we don’t actually need to compute it;

```
port rdeps mtr 2>/dev/null | sed -E "1 s/.*of (.*) @.*/\1/" |
     while IFS= read -r line
     do
         space_num="$(port space --units MiB --total $line 2>/dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
         printf "%-20s%12.2f %s\n" "$line" "$space_num" "MiB"
     done
```

does the same as the above.

## With Truncation

To simply truncate numbers,
it’s best to treat them as strings rather than as numbers. 
This command

```
port rdeps mtr 2>/dev/null | sed -E "1 s/.*of (.*) @.*/\1/" |
     while IFS= read -r line
     do
         printf "%-30s%s\n" "$line" \
                  "$(port space --units MiB --total $line 2>/dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2)"
     done | sed -E -e 's/(\..*) /\100 /' -e 's/(.{25}) *(....\...).*( .*)/\1\2\3/'
```

starts off as pretty much the same as my previous answer. 
But then it pipes everything through a `sed`, which has two parts:

- `s/(\..*) /\100 /`
  This matches the decimal point (`\.`)
  and any number of characters after it (`.*`)
  up to, but not including, a space character. 
  Then it replaces the whole match string
  with the part before the space (`\1`), two zeroes, and a space. 
  (I could have said `s/(\..*)( )/\100\2/`; it would done the same thing.) 
  This changes `0.088 MiB` to `0.08800 MiB` and `0.0 MiB` to `0.000 MiB`. 
  If you had `42. MiB` in your data, it would change it to `42.00 MiB`. 
  But note that it assumes that every number has a decimal point,
  even if it doesn’t have any digits after it. 
  (It also assumes that there are no periods
  in the strings `mtr`, `pkgconfig`, `libiconv`, etc.)

  We need to do this to ensure
  that there *are* at least two digits after the decimal point in every number;
  that is not the case for `gperf` until we make this correction.
- `s/(.{25}) *(....\...).*( .*)/\1\2\3/`
  `.{25}` is short for `.........................`;
  i.e., 25 arbitrary characters. 
  I assume this is long enough to capture the longest (e.g., `libiconv`),
  most deeply indented, string. 
  Then any number of characters (`.*`),
  which, in fact, I expect to be just a bunch of spaces. 
  Then `....\...` matches four characters, a decimal point,
  and two more characters. 
  If you ever have a space number bigger than `9999`,
  you’ll have to change this
  to match more than four digits to the left of the decimal point. 
  Then any number of characters (`.*`),
  which will be any digits after the first two after the decimal point. 
  Then a space and the rest of the line (`( .*)`),
  which I expect to be  `MiB`. 
  Then it puts the pieces back together as the string
  (with the appropriate leading and following spaces),
  the number (with enough leading spaces
  to make the **`.`** the fifth character in `\2`), and then the units.

The output from this command looks like

```
mtr                         0.08 MiB
  pkgconfig                 0.61 MiB
    libiconv                6.27 MiB
      gperf                 0.00 MiB
  glib2                    46.09 MiB
    xz                      1.67 MiB
      gettext              24.82 MiB
        expat               1.10 MiB
        ncurses            15.17 MiB
    libxml2                10.40 MiB
      zlib                  0.72 MiB
    libffi                  0.14 MiB
    pcre                    5.95 MiB
      bzip2                 0.64 MiB
      libedit               0.79 MiB
```

Note that `0.088 MiB` got truncated to `0.08 MiB`.

Of course you can put any of the above compound commands all on one line
if you want, and you should adjust the width constants
(`12`, `20`, `25`, `30`, etc.) to meet your needs.

Comment: That was a great answer. It helped me format the output for [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/240638/39640). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you appear to realize, `printf` is a great tool for formatted printing. 
As you probably have learned, `%s` is the format to output a string. 
`%20s` outputs a 20-character long string, right justified,
padded with spaces on the left (if necessary). 
`%-20s` does the opposite — it outputs a 20-character long string,
left justified, padded with spaces on the right (if necessary). 
So, for example, the commands

```
printf "%-20s%s\n" "mtr" "0.088 MiB"
printf "%-20s%s\n" "  pkgconfig" "0.615 MiB"
printf "%-20s%s\n" "    libiconv" "6.270 MiB"
          ︙
```

will produce the output

```
mtr                 0.088 MiB
  pkgconfig         0.615 MiB
    libiconv        6.270 MiB
       ︙
```

So you should be able to get the result you want with this command:

```
port rdeps mtr 2>/dev/null | sed -E "1 s/.*of (.*) @.*/\1/" |
     while IFS= read -r line
     do
         printf "%-20s%s\n" "$line" \
                  "$(port space --units MiB --total $line 2>/dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2)"
     done
```

I often recommend that you should always quote `$` references
(e.g., variables) in shell commands and scripts
unless you have a good reason not to. 
Note that I put the `$(…)` expression into quotes. 
But, since `$line` contains leading spaces, it is quite possible that

```
port space --units MiB --total "$line"
```

would not work.

Of course you can put the above compound command all on one line if you want,
and you should adjust the `20` to your needs.

Comment: That's a great answer. However, it doesn't take into account justifying by a char (the floating point). So, for example, it'd output  `    libiconv                  6.270 MiB
      gperf                   0.0 MiB
  glib2                       46.092 MiB`  wrongly aligned. And then also the unit would be misaligned. Although I'd probably rather have it cut (not rounded) to two digits, it'd still need zero-padding in some cases.

Comment: See, this is why I said "***show us*** what the input looks like, and ***what you want the output to look like.***" When you say, "... I'd probably rather have *X* ..., it'd still need *Y* in some cases," you're asking us to read your mind.

Comment: Fair enough. I updated the question.

Comment: Hello? I've written a new answer; do you care?

Comment: Hello, G-Man. I do care and I'll check it thoroughly as soon as I can. Thanks.