# how to keep n decimal places?

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting, numeric-data

I have a file with 40,000 rows

```
head flower_all

    0.992957746478873 0.00704225352112677
    0.646410833917366 0.353589166082634
    0.992957746478873 0.00704225352112677
    0.992957746478873 0.00704225352112677
    0.992957746478873 0.00704225352112677
    0.992957746478873 0.00704225352112677
    0.992957746478873 0.00704225352112677
    0.992957746478873 0.00704225352112677
    0.5 0.5
```

I want to keep only 3 significant digits.
My desired output:

```
0.992 0.007
0.646 0.353
0.992 0.007
0.992 0.007
0.992 0.007
0.992 0.007
0.992 0.007
0.992 0.007
0.5 0.5
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Each row contains only two columns?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to truncate rather then round (0.992 vs 0.993)? Also some of your example results are three decimal places not three significant figures (0.007 vs 0.00704). Which do you want?

Comment: Loosely related: [format command output with variable and fixed space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272374/23408)

Answer (score 11):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf("%.3g %.3g\n", $1, $2) }' file
```

With the given data, this produces

```
0.993 0.00704
0.646 0.354
0.993 0.00704
0.993 0.00704
0.993 0.00704
0.993 0.00704
0.993 0.00704
0.993 0.00704
0.5 0.5
```

Note that 0.00704 has five decimals, but three significant digits.

If you want exactly three decimals, use `%.3f` instead of `%.3g` and get

```
0.993 0.007
0.646 0.354
0.993 0.007
0.993 0.007
0.993 0.007
0.993 0.007
0.993 0.007
0.993 0.007
0.500 0.500
```

The two variation above may be generalised for a variable number of columns, using GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v CONVFMT='%.3g' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i+=0; print }' file
```

The loop with `$i+=0` forces `awk` to re-format the value of every field as a floating point number, which it will do while taking `CONVFMT` into account (it will more or less do the equivalent of `$i=sprintf(CONVFMT, $i)`).

---

If you want to *cut* the numbers:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i=sprintf("%.5s", $i); print }' file
```

This treats the numbers as strings and cuts them off after five characters (which assumes that all numbers are less than 10 and greater than zero) generating

```
0.992 0.007
0.646 0.353
0.992 0.007
0.992 0.007
0.992 0.007
0.992 0.007
0.992 0.007
0.992 0.007
0.5 0.5
```

For a slightly more general cutting of the numbers:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (match($i,".*\\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?")) $i=substr($i,RSTART,RLENGTH); print }' file
```

The operation in the loop cuts the numbers at the point at which the given regular expression match ends (if it matches).

Answer (score 3):

Your data has no numbers above 1. I extended the source file to include some values with more digits before the dot:

```
$ cat infile
0.992957746478873 0.00704225352112677
0.646410833917366 0.353589166082634
0.992957746478873 0.00704225352112677
0.5 0.5
16.258137489137 333444.277775666
16.233399999999 333777.277111111
```

## printf

One possible solution is to use the C compatible printf function (awk has one):

#### the f format (3 (rounded) decimal places)

An exact count of 3 (rounded) decimals:

```
$ awk '{ printf("%11.3f %11.3f\n", $1,$2) }' infile
      0.993       0.007
      0.646       0.354
      0.993       0.007
      0.500       0.500
     16.258  333444.278
     16.233  333777.277
```

Note that `0.992957746478873` is rounded up to `0.993`.

#### the g format (significant (rounded))

An exact count of 3 (significant) digits:

```
$ awk '{ printf("%9.3g %9.3g\n", $1,$2) }' infile
    0.993   0.00704
    0.646     0.354
    0.993   0.00704
      0.5       0.5
     16.3  3.33e+05
     16.2  3.34e+05
```

Note the rounding on the forth digit (for example 3.34e+05)

## String (not rounded)

Exactly 3 (not rounded) digits after the decimal dot.

Using GNU awk:

```
$ gawk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
         printf( "%12s ",gensub(/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{0,3}).*/, "\\1", "g", $i))};print""}
       ' infile
       0.992        0.007
       0.646        0.353
       0.992        0.007
         0.5          0.5
      16.258   333444.277
      16.233   333777.277
```

Using sed (probably faster):

```
$ sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,3})[^ ]*/\1/g' infile
0.992 0.007
0.646 0.353
0.992 0.007
0.5 0.5
16.258 333444.277
16.233 333777.277
```

Comment: Thanks for the string not included.